# Are there no standard syntax highlighting in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

Whatever language I select there are no syntax highlighting. Just the font color and background color are changing. In other editors there default syntax highlighting and they are pretty good.

**Update showing selecting language does not make syntax highlighting:**

[image: selecting language]

[image: nothing happens after selecting python]

[image: the same code in Programmers Notebook with default highlighting]

**UPDATE**

Here's what's happenning with style configurator as I commented to Sathya. Increasing font size increases line height:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you opening files that have a file extension? If not, you should be able to select what language are using in a drop-down menu.

Comment: @Pubby8, I added images showing that selecting a language from the menu does not change the screen display. The last picture shows the same code in Programmers Notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I can't simulate this - have you overridden the default syntax highlighting rules?</s>

Head over to `Settings` -> `Style Configurator` and ensure that the syntax highlighting rules are present

---

I see what you're saying now - changing font setting for individual language does not seem to apply the font setting. Seems like a bug with Notepad++.

As a alternative, set the  Global Font overrides as shown [in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CmFP.png)

[image: Notepad++ global font settings]

[image: Font increased to 16]

[image: Font increased to 24]

Comment: @Satya thanks I uninstalled the program and I will reinstall it and see what happens

Comment: I installed it again. The logic of this Style Configurator does not make sense. I choose a theme as shown in your image; I select a language; then I change font size... and what happens? the line spacing between line increases but not the font size! I change the font but font is not changing. I gave up and I click cancel and the alert tells me that there are unsaved changes... I want to use Notepad++ but I cannot because of this issue. Style configurator just does not work for me. Can you help. Say I want to change font and font size in javascript what do I do?

Comment: Updated @Zynel. Also , once you created a new file you'll have to select the language from Language -> J -> Javascript to apply the syntax highlighting rules. http://i.imgur.com/taDR6.jpg | http://i.imgur.com/TnODV.jpg | http://i.imgur.com/oxbdg.jpg. However, since we have a global override, it'll pick up font settings mentioned in the answer. If you're opening a saved file, this step isn't needed